# How can I move to the end of a tag using BeautifulSoup in python?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I have html as follows:

```
html = '<html><table>this is a table<p>some text</p></table><p>text outside of table</p></html>'
```

I want to move to the end of table and then find the next tag.  I tried using findNext but if there is a tag inside the table it finds that tag instead of the next tag outside of the table.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(text))
table = soup.find('table')
test = table.findNext()
```

This code gives me:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

However, I want it to give me:

```
<p>text outside of table</p>
```

The main problem is that I can't always specify that a tag is a 'p' tag.  I could have html like this:

```
html = '<html><table>this is a table<td>some text</td></table><table>text outside of table</table></html>'
```

So, I can't really rely on the tag identifiers to get to the next one.  In the above code, I want to return:

```
<table>text outside of table</table>
```

I realize that I could just use findNext twice, but often there are hundreds of tags inside each table and so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would

```
test = table.nextSibling
```

work for you?

Comment: Wow, i feel dumb.  I tried using findNextSibling and it wasn't working.  I guess I should read the documentation more carefully.  Thanks.